# Fastest way to assign series to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert a series of a dataframe. The dataframe has about ~1M rows. The conversion works fine, but I noticed that assigning the series back to the dataframe (same column, with same index, name, etc) takes a lot of time (supposedly because the index is aligned, data is copied and some validation which isn't necessary).

Is there a way to bypass all of this and assign the new series to the dataframe?

My current (slow approach is):

```
s1 = df[c]
s2 = convert(s1)
df[c] = s2
```

Is there anything glaringly obvious that I could try? I tried `.loc[:, c] = s2`, `.iloc[:, c_index] = s2` and `.loc[s2.index, c] = s2`, but there wasn't much of a difference. What other ways are there which I could try out?

Comment: Can you try: `df[c] = convert(df[c]).to_numpy()` or  `df[c] = convert(df[c]).values`? Of course if the Series is already aligned. You can also directly return the array from the function.

Comment: The fastest way would be to vectorize your convert function and apply it to the dataframe directly. Would you be able to share the convert function so that we can show how an example of how that might work ?

Comment: @Jesse although it would be interesting to see the function, OP mentioned that computation is not the problem, but assignment is. Orange: can you give the specific timings of each step?

Comment: Is the dtype changing during conversion? Can your conversion take a numpy array as input instead of a Series?

Comment: I'm not suggesting the convert function needs changed in any way but is it written in such a way that map or apply can be used directly.

Comment: Dtype is changing to a custom EA dtype. The conversion is not an issue (maybe forget about it for sake of simplicity), but the assignment is (takes about 0.150s and needs to be done for several dataframes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that

```
df._iset_item_mgr(column_pos, arr, inplace=True)
```

shortcuts a lot of the validation and copying of data, but it still only shaves off a few milliseconds for my 1Mx100 dataset. The limiting factor is a call to `nb = blk.delete(blk_locs)` in `pandas/core/internals/managers.py` in `BlockManager.iset`. `blk.delete` essentially deletes the column `c` (in `df[c]._iset_item_grp`) via `np.delete(...)` as the type during the conversion changed and the new array `arr` is attached to another block.

I don't think there's anything that can be done to resolve this as the BlockManager is an integral part of Pandas (and I went all the way down through all the layers of Pandas to the backing numpy matrix).

I resorted to a completely different strategy avoiding conversion entirely. I hope this is helpful to someone who stumbles upon this problem.